# How to insert links to image banner slider in jQuery Plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

How to insert links to image slider in jQuery Plugin?

I got slider source from http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Responsive-jQuery-Full-Width-Image-Slider-Plugin-responsiveSlides.html

I try insert links like this :

```
<a href="www.google.coom"><img src="blablabla.jpg></a>
```

but, It does not work ... (T^T)
I recheck in Chrome (key F12)

```
<div class="tgtimg" style="position:absolute !important; height:600px !important; width:100% !important; background:#fff !important; z-index:1 !important; overflow:hidden !important"><img src="http://ikkorea.i.hhosting.kr/main/main_20150710_1.jpg" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: -568.5px; height: 600px; display: block;" class="current"></div>

   <a href="http://search.naver.com/search.naver?sm=tab_hty.top&amp;where=nexearch&amp;ie=utf8&amp;query=%EC%9D%B5%EC%8A%A4%ED%8E%98%EB%94%94%EC%95%84+%EB%8F%84%EC%B0%A9"></a>
```

How can I?

this is my site:
http://www.istkunst.co.kr/preview/?dgnset_id=5834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an global `class` to all the images you want to be clicked, and add also the link for every image in `data-link`, like this :

**HTML :**

```
<div id="content">
    <img class="img_link" data-link="www.google.com" src="1.jpg">
    <img class="img_link" data-link="www.gmail.com"  src="2.jpg">
    <img class="img_link" data-link="www.yahoo.com"  src="3.jpg">
</div>
```

Create fucntion to handle the click on images and redirect to the related link stored in `data-link` , just after the call of `responsiveSlides()`.

**JS :**

```
$(function(){

    var p=$('#content').responsiveSlides({
        ....
    });

    //Handling click event and redirecting to the related link
    $('.img_link').click(function(){
        window.location.replace($(this).data('link'));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it instead so that there is a on click listener for the tgtimg class that will auto redirect.

```
$('.tgtimg').click(function(){
      window.location = "url you want";
});
```

That's a possible work around you could use if it you get really desperate.

**EDIT**

You might also want to try out the jquery wrap method.

```
$('.tgtimg').children('img').wrap('<a href="www.google.com"></a>');
```